# using GPS error mtdef.MTException: fixed point precision not supported

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I appreciate your fast response on this.

I am using the Xsense MTi-G710 with all outputs enabled.
Inside the building without a GPS fix everything is fine. Once I get outside to open sky and get a fix, the driver fails showing this message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/renawi/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_xsens_driver/nodes/mtnode.py", line 717, in 
main()
File "/home/renawi/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_xsens_driver/nodes/mtnode.py", line 713, in main
driver.spin()
File "/home/renawi/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_xsens_driver/nodes/mtnode.py", line 122, in spin
self.spin_once()
File "/home/renawi/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_xsens_driver/nodes/mtnode.py", line 629, in spin_once
data = self.mt.read_measurement()
File "/home/renawi/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_xsens_driver/nodes/mtdevice.py", line 632, in read_measurement
return self.parse_MTData2(data)
File "/home/renawi/catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_xsens_driver/nodes/mtdevice.py", line 912, in parse_MTData2
raise MTException("fixed point precision not supported.")
mtdef.MTException: fixed point precision not supported.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257370/using-gps-error-mtdef.mtexception:-fixed-point-precision-not-supported/) by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed!
I changed the settings of the GPS data to floating point.

---

Originally posted by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) with karma: 31 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ubicray](https://answers.ros.org/users/31004/ubicray/) on 2017-08-02**:
Where and how did you change it?

**Comment by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) on 2017-08-06**:
I Installed the Xsense manager on a windows PC and connected the sensor to it. There you find an option to change thr GPS data type.